# syncing c# app and the device through serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I developed a c# application which is read the device through serial port. I achieve write to it but not properly. Now my sceneraio is the formatting the device through serial port automatically. First of all i have to send a keypress when the device wait for it(when i see in the richtextbox "hit any key to stop autoboot"). How can I do that? I achieve this with writing to the serial port (serialport1.write("xxxx\r\n")) when i get the hit message in the richtextbox but i think it is not a good idea to fallow the richtextbox. Can you suggest any other way?

My important question is let's think about we handle the hit message and stop autobooting. Now we have to send commands to the device for formating. For example first one is fdisk command, second one is ext3format and third one is fatformat. These commands takes time when you send these to the device. how can i sync my commands and the device, because when i trying to do that i got some problems. The problem is i have to send other command after the first command sent and device finished its job. I can only fallow the richtextbox and according to the output i m trying to send the fallowing commands. Can you suggest any other way? Do i have to fallow richtextbox outputs, is there any other way to understand the device finishes its job after sending commands?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you are using a remote console into the device via a serial port connection (telnet?), and the device is using linux. so basically you are simulating user input and output in your program.

You need to recognize the output the device is sending byte by byte, first of all.  Do not focus on the "richtextbox", you are only using that to display what you get from the device.

You need to process the serial data as it comes in and look for patterns of data that you recognize (for example, the result code from the format command, the text sent over when the command prompt is visible again, etc).

When it says "hit any key", you need to send a character over the serial port that the device recognizes.

you also need to know which terminal mode emulation (google this) the device is expecting you to use, because this affects how you should format codes sent to the device and how you should interpret characters you receive from it.

What you want to do is straightforward, basically you are writing an automated remote terminal for the device, but it does require some reading on your part, and stop focusing on what a textbox displays and start focusing on the data bytes going into and out of your device.

Comment: "and stop focusing on what a textbox displays and start focusing on the data bytes going into and out of your device" ... excellent advice! Its a side effect of all these RAD tools where lazy/weak developers use UI widgets as quick and nasty replacements for proper data structures!  Rant Over :)